# Table update based on match/nomatch

Tags: sql, oracle, join, sql-update

I have two tables `t1` and `t2`.

`t1` has this structure:

```
yearmonth
account
company
RCV_amount_t1
```

`t2` has this structure:

```
yearmonth
account 
company
billing amount
billing amount CM_1
billing amount CM_2
RCV_amount_t2
```

I want to join `t2` to `t1` using `yearmonth`, `account`, and `company`.  If they match, I want to update `RCV_amount_t2` with the value in `RCG_amount_t1`.  Otherwise, I want to set `RCV_amount_t2` to spaces.

In the same manner, I want to join `t1` with `t2` using `yearmonth`, `account`, and `company` and set values accordingly.

Is it possible to achieve?  If so, how do I go about it?

Comment: I'm puzzled by the sentence "In the same manner...."  If you first update all rows in T2 with values from T1 where there is a match, what would be the point of doing the same update in reverse?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to use a [`MERGE`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_9016.htm).
It allows you to join two tables and specify how to update the values if they match.

The general structure of a `MERGE` statement looks like:

```
MERGE INTO driver_table
USING other_table
ON
(
    driver_table.column1 = other_table.column1
AND driver_table.column2 = other_table.column2
AND ...
)
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE
    SET
        driver_table.some_column = other_table.some_value,
        driver_table.some_flag = 'Y',
        ...
;
```

Comment: However, the question states "[If there is no match], I want to set RCV_amount_t2 to spaces."  I don't believe a MERGE would support that.

Comment: @DaveCosta - It wouldn't.  You'd probably start by blanking *all* the `RCV_amount_t2` values to spaces, then updating the ones that do match.  It would have the same effect.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to join t2 to t1 using yearmonth, account, and company. If they
>   match, I want to update RCV_amount_t2 with the value in RCG_amount_t1.
>   Otherwise, I want to set RCV_amount_t2 to spaces.

This will update the matching rows with the appropriate value, and update the rows with no match to `NULL`.  If the field is numeric, you can't update it to "spaces"; `NULL` would be the appropriate indicator of no value.  If the field is not numeric, then you could do a second update to replace `NULL` values with whatever you like, but `NULL` would still seem to me to be the most appropriate indicator of no value.

```
UPDATE t2 SET rcv_amount_t2 = (
  SELECT rcv_amount_t1
    FROM t1
    WHERE t1.yearmonth = t2.yearmonth
    AND t1.account = t2.account
    AND t1.company = t2.company
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that we cannot resolve it in a single query, we need a [merge](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_9016.htm#SQLRF01606) and a [correlated query](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_10002.htm#i2066912), It works fine for me:

This will update t2 with values from t1 when matched:

```
MERGE INTO t2
   USING (SELECT yearmonth, account, company, RCV_amount_t1 FROM t1) S
   ON (t1.yearmonth = t2.yearmonth and
       t1.account = t2.account and
       t1.company = t2.company)
   WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET t2.RCV_amount_t2 = S.RCV_amount_t1;
```

Then a query containg a corrolated subquery to blank when not matched:

```
update t2 set RCV_amount_t2 = '    ' where yearmonth||account||company not in(
select yearmonth||account||company from t1 
where t1.yearmonth = t2.yearmonth and t1.account=t2.account and t1.company=t2.company);
```